# Function parameters become an array

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell function

```
function Foo($a, $b){
  '$a = ' + $a
  '$b = ' + $b
}
```

I invoke it by calling

```
Foo("dogs", "cat");
```

Everything I've read so far says the expected output is

```
$a = dogs
$b = cats
```

What I'm actually seeing is:

```
$a = dogs cat
$b =
```

If I rewrite my function as:

```
function Foo($a, $b){
  '$a is ' + $a.GetType().Name;
  '$b = ' + $b.GetType().Name;
}
```

The output is:

```
$a is Object[]
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\WCMTeam\Percussion\Notifier\foo.ps1:4 char:7
+       '$b = ' + $b.GetType().Name;
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Apparently $a and $b are being combined into a single array.  What am I doing to cause this and how should I change it to get my expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call your function using

```
Foo "dogs" "cats"
```

`,` is used to separate array elements in Powershell, so

```
Foo "dogs", "cats"
```

calls `Foo` with a single array argument, which is assigned to `$a`.

Comment: Calling it as `Foo("dogs" "cats")` causes it to fail with the error "Unexpected token '"cats"' in expression or statement."  But changing it to just `Foo "dogs" "cats"` does indeed solve the problem.  Thank you; this is as maddening as the parentheses rules in VBScript.

Comment: Listen to the man (Lee). You shouldn't be using `(` and `)` at all in your function calls. PowerShell is not equal to c#, PS has it's own language (although much .Net / C# code work).

Comment: Oh, I'm listening all right.  Just finding the transition a bit disorienting. :-/